# Links in div on top of clickable image is unreachable

Tags: html, css

I have [this website](http://shop.snaptee.co/collections/albert-einstein) in which users can click on any of the hashtags shown under a product's details to search for similar products. The product image is an `<img>` tag wrapped in an `<a>` tag, taking you to the product page.

[image]

However, when you hover over any of the products and click on the hashtag, it takes you to the product page instead of the search page. (i.e. browsers redirects as if the image itself was clicked, not the hashtag).

I've tried adding `z-index`s to the anchor links themselves with no avail. How do I fix this?

Comment: Instead of adding it to the anchor links, add `z-index` to the containing parent element which wraps the by, hashtag and price

Comment: @mohamedrias The parent already has `z-index: 5; position: absolute;`; without this I wouldn't be able to get it to stack on top of the image.

Comment: `z-index` should be relative. http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/css-how-to-use-the-z-index-property/

Comment: @0aslam0 `z-index` also works with `absolute` or `fixed`

Comment: To the person who downvoted this question, exactly why did you downvote it?

Comment: Add your HTML here, reproduce the problem outside your site. Otherwise once the problem is fixed, this question doesnt have any value for future reference...

Comment: @Vishwanath problem is I can't seem to reproduce on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyteen4a03/j1feL9xq/), and us compiling directly from SCSS to CSS doesn't help with replicating the formatting. I noticed that the whitspaces in the product description div aren't clickable on jsfiddle while it is on the website.

Comment: A way to fix this problem can be use <div> instead of <a> for product and add an onclick on the same using jquery 

`$('.product-image').click(function(){
   location.href=$(this).data('url')
})`

Using data-url property.

Answer (score 1):

Nested anchor tags are illegal and should not be used.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2 states

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.
>
> Since the DTD defines the LINK element to be empty, LINK elements may not be nested either.

Comment: If you read the HTML, they are not nested. They are simply stacked on top of one another visually.